# I'm trying to upload an image to firebase storage and get the download url

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Newbie here, I'm trying to upload an image to firebase storage and then get the download url. Then I'll add that url as data to save on firestore. I'm able to upload successfully and get the image reference but the problem is with `getDownloadURL()`. I'm having trouble formatting the promise. I've tried multiple ways but can't seem to figure it out.

```
TypeError: ref._throwIfRoot is not a function
    at getDownloadURL$1 (index.esm2017.js?f61e:2956:1)
    at getDownloadURL (index.esm2017.js?f61e:3412:1)
    at eval (cloudStorageFunctions.js?05e1:17:34)
```

```
const productImagesRef = ref(storage, 'images/product-images');

function getImageURL(fileName, file) {
    const filePath = `${productImagesRef}/${fileName}`;
    const imageRef = ref(storage, filePath);

    return uploadBytes(imageRef, file)
        .then(snapshot => {
            console.log(`File: ${fileName} uploaded successfully.`);
            return snapshot.metadata.fullPath;      
        })
        .then(path => {
            console.log(typeof path, path);
            return getDownloadURL(path);
        })
        .then(src => {
            console.log(src);
            return src;
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
        })
}
```

The data is submitted via a form:

```
async function handleSubmit() {
        let src = await getImageURL(imageName, imageFile);

        setImageSrc(src);

        const data = {
            id: id,
            imageSrc: imageSrc,
            description: description,
            category: category,
            discount: discount,
            discountPrice: discountPrice,
            price: price,
            sizes: sizes,
            totalQuantity: quantity,
            type: type,
        }

        console.log(data);

        if(imageSrc) await addProducts(data);
        
        setImageFile('');
        setImageName('');
        setImageSrc('');
        setDescription('');
        setCategory('');
        setDiscount(false);
        setDiscountPrice(0);
        setPrice('');
        setSizes([]);
        setQuantity('');
        setType([]);
        setDisplay('none')

        alert('Added');
    }
```

Comment: "I'm having trouble formatting the promise" I'm not really sure what that means. What does the `console.log(src);` output?

Comment: I just tried `getDownloadURL(imageRef)` which returns the url when I `console.log(src)`. It's weird because I tried that before and it didn't work, but thanks. Now my problem is returning that `src` so I can `setImageSrc(src)`. I feel like I'm formatting my promise wrong towards the end.

Comment: In other words `imageSrc` comes up as an empty string.

Comment: By "formatting promise" I meant that I wasn't using the syntax for a promise properly. Sorry for the confusion. I'm able to get the `src` url but for whatever reason I can't `setImageSrc(src)`. It always comes up as an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`uploadBytes` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage#uploadbytes) returns a `Promise<UploadResult>`. You're passing that result to the [`getDownloadURL` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage#getdownloadurl), but that expects a `StorageReference`.

Simple fix:

```
return uploadBytes(imageRef, file)
    .then(snapshot => {
        return snapshot.metadata.fullPath;      
    })
    .then(path => {
        return getDownloadURL(imageRef);
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

`getDownloadURL` takes a storage reference just like the one you passed to `uplaodBytes`.

```
return getDownloadURL(imagePath);
```

It's not clear to me what you are currently passing instead.  I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) for an example.